# Binding lost after call service in angular 5

Tags: angular, data-binding

I want my url change by parameter id. The question is the data is big, so I want load the whole data at beginning. However I found once the url changed, the code goes to ngOnInit and the data lost. So I have to reload it, it is very slow. So I create a global service class to store the data, if the url changes then I compare whether the data is null or undefined. If it is null then I retrieve the data from the global service. Of course I store the data at the beginning. It works looks good. However I found a wild thing, which is sometimes the binding on the form or textbox are lost if the code runs at getDataFromGlobalService method. I think maybe the async issue or something else.

```
const url = 'apps/mycase/';
this.router.navigate([url], {queryParms: {id: this.id}});
if(this.data)
this.loadingData();
else
this.getDataFromGlobalService();


ngOnInit() {
   this.data = this.globalService.getData();
   this.loadDropDownData();
}
```

The method getDataFromGlobalService

```
private getDataFromGlobalService() {
 // here still binding
   if(!this.data) {
        this.service['some'].get().subscribe(d => {
            this.data = d;
            this.globalService.setBackupData(this.data);
         };
   }
   else { // the binding lost here if code arrive here
       otherthings();

   }
}

The global service is simple.

@Injectable()
export class GlobalService {
   public data: any;
   constructor() {
       this.data = null;
   }
   public setBackData = (data: any) => {
        this.data = data;
   }

   public getData = () => {
      return this.data;
   }
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something in my code. For some reason, I had the code

```
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = false;
```

I wanted to use because of the router having parameter. Now if I remove it, the bindings are back. Not sure why it caused the issue in the specific step. Hopefully somebody can give me an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

this is just how javascript and object reference storage works.  changing the service level reference won't change the reference in all other service or components that have previously stored the old reference.  The components aren't storing a reference to the service's reference, they're storing a reference to whatever object the service was referencing at the time of assignment.  This is why you use rxjs.

```
   @Injectable()
   export class GlobalService {
     private dataSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null); // private subject, behavior subject will remember last value
     getData$ = this.dataSource.asObservable(); // public observable
     constructor() {
       this.data = null;
     }
     public setBackData = (data: any) => {
       this.dataSource.next(data); // call next to set new data
     }
   }


ngOnInit() {
   this.sub = this.globalService.getData$.subscribe(data => this.data = data); // subscribe and assign, store subscription
   this.loadDropDownData();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.sub.unsubscribe(); // unsubscribe to avoid memory leaks
}
```

Comment: I guess that my rxjs version less than 6, does your code work?

Comment: `this.data` is a local object defined in the component. So you are saying even  I assign it to a value locally, it is just a reference?

Comment: objects and arrays are always stored by reference in javascript

Comment: It seems something else. Your code is working, I modified my code. I appreciate it. But the thing is I have a formgroup, which binds the properties. Even the `this.data` is still there, but once the code executes the method `getDataFromGlobalService`, the form lost binding. I check the form value, it became `undefined`. Before that it has values.